PHP 8.2.7 compilation does not work when cURL is included
I get the following installing PHP:
php-8.2.7/ext/curl/interface.c:3085: undefined reference to `curl_easy_upkeep'
I thought this would be a common error (hence the post) and I have tried the following so far:

dnf install curl curl-devel
installed latest cURL to /usr/local/curl (can see lib and include directories)
tried several times including without curl in the configure command for PHP

So if anyone can beat me to it kudos to you.
For reference the full output of the error is:
lcrypto -lcrypt -lrt -o sapi/cli/php
ext/curl/interface.o: In function `zif_curl_upkeep':
/tmp/serverforge/downloads/php-8.2.7/ext/curl/interface.c:3085: undefined reference to `curl_easy_upkeep'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:310: sapi/cli/php] Error 1

I tried installing PHP from source (8.2.7) and I expected to have it install with cURL but only works without cURL in the php 8.7.2 configure command.
The full command I used was: ./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/php82 --enable-cli --enable-fpm --program-suffix=82 --with-xsl --with-libxml=/usr/local/libxml2 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs --enable-bcmath --with-bz2=/usr/local/bzip2 --enable-calendar --with-curl=/usr/local/curl --enable-ftp --enable-gd --with-libdir=lib64 --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --enable-intl --enable-mbstring --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-xsl --enable-soap --enable-sockets; make; make install;
Note also, that /usr/local/curl/bin/curl --version outputs 8.8.0.
EDIT
I have since discovered that both php74 and php80 compile fine. Can anybody understand what is happening here?
The cURL version is listed below, the libcurl that appears after is installed out of my control, so I do not know where to find it.
[root@localhost]# curl -V curl 8.8.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.8.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 zstd/1.4.4 OpenLDAP/2.4.46 Release-Date: 2024-05-22 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ipfs ipns ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd 
I changed the hard links for which curl-config to symlink to /usr/local/curl/bin/curl-config which changed the output but did not change the fact that it doesn't compile.
From looking at my system:
    /usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.a
    /usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.la
    /usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.so
    /usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.so.4
    /usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.so.4.7.0
    /usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.so.4.8.0
    /usr/local/lib/libcurl.a
    /usr/local/lib/libcurl.la
    /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so
    /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
    /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.7.0

There are two installations it seems. How do I make it so the right installation is used? Currently --with-curl=/usr/local/curl is not doing it.
FYI:
[root@localhost]# curl-config --version
libcurl 8.8.0
[root@localhost]# curl-config --help
[root@localhost]# curl-config --static-libs
/usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.a -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -llber -lzstd -lz -pthread
[root@localhost bin]# curl-config --ca
"/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
[root@localhost]# curl-config --cc
gcc
[root@localhost]# curl-config --libs
-L/usr/local/curl/lib -lcurl


Compiling PHP from source code is a goal on itself or just a workaround because you can't make your Linux distro packages work?

Yes it's a goal, I am compiling from source as is standard, no?

I wouldn't say it's standard, especially in the Linux world. In the BSD world, more so. If you want to program in PHP, use packages. If you work on PHP itself, you could probably reproduce those packages' build procedure, which often includes patches or dependencies on specific versions.

I'd of said it is a devops first choice, which is the use-case here.

/usr/local/curl/bin/curl --version outputs 8.8.0, but what version of libcurl is installed, or more importantly, what is the version and location of libcurl that PHP is finding and building against? The error implies that the version of libcurl being linked against is older than 7.62.0, because the function curl_easy_upkeep was added in that version and it is not found in the curl PHP is linking against. You should be able to find it in the file include/curl/curlver.h from the location where the curl headers are installed.

The headers might actually show libcurl newer than 7.62.0 but the actual shared libraries it's using are older, because PHP has a conditional where it won't compile in that function if the installed libcurl version isn't new enough to have curl_easy_upkeep.

I feel you are right but don't know how to update all the variants you described. Maybe post an answer with more guidance?

For "common" versions of linux, compiling from source is pretty unusual because it takes forever, and requires installing a whole bunch of stuff that most people never need. Instead, you use apt or yum etc. to install the thing you need. If you're compiling from source, then you'll have to meticuloulsy go through the configure output to see if it's flagging anything that it won't be able to do, not just look at the errors you get all the way at the end: which features did it flag as not available, which things did it flag as warning-but-not-error, etc.

But as a process, rather than a programming problem per se, this is almost certainly better asked on the PHP mailing list or user group, because it's going to be a back and forth where you try something, someone recommends something, you try something again, someone else recommends something, etc. etc. which is the exact opposite of how SO works, where you ask something in as much detail as you can, so that folks can post an answer without ever having to post a comment. So if you want to keep it here, at least explain every possible detail

I'm developing software that installs PHP and from source is the better way of doing it, I feel. The system I'm developing on is AlmaLinux. I'll try to include more information, thank you.

[root@localhost bin]# curl-config --version libcurl 7.73.0
Could this be the problem?

Have a look at this project: https://github.com/crazywhalecc/static-php-cli wich is a superset of this: https://github.com/easysoft/phpmicro/blob/master/Readme.EN.md

There are two installations it seems after searching for 'libcurl' (question updated). How do I make it so the right installation is used? Currently --with-curl=/usr/local/curl is not doing it.

From your file listing, it seems you have 2x libcurl installations on your system:

/usr/local/curl/lib
/usr/local/lib

Due to multiple installations, the build process MIGHT still link against older libcurl... So let's have a fresh start:

Rrefresh the library cache: ldconfig
Check which version of libcurl is PHP trying to use: ldd /usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.so
Clear the build artifacts: make clean
Ensure CORRECT version of libcurl is specified in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to prioritize this path for linking: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/curl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
You can also add PKG_CONFIG_PATH to make sure pkg-config picks up the correct libcurl.pc: export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/curl/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Reconfigure PHP with your own params: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php82...
Build it: make
Verify the CORRECT linked library: ldd sapi/cli/php | grep curl and php -i | grep cURL

Failed? you can specify linker flags manually in configure command:
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/curl/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/curl/include" ...


Legend. Thank you.
